# Java library to implement oauth2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I have a web application written using JSP and Servlets.

I needed to know if there is any Java library to implement my own OAuth2.0 login mechanism. I am referring this http://oauth.net/2/ , but I dont find enough information on these libraries to get started.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Oltu is one such library, and they seem to have fairly comprehensive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Documentation).